# Using pivot_longer() to gather up hundreds of like variables using REGEX tidyr

Tags: r, regex, pivot, tidyr, reshape

I have a question regarding pivot_longer() which does not appear to have been previously discussed. The dataset has over 10 thousand columns, but only 242 rows. Below only holds information for estimates, across all of these are 21 other variables (lower CI vs subtype etc) and they must be lengthened as well.

```r
TEST_table <- structure(list(
Estimate.1.Country.... = c("45", "", "22", "39", "23", "2"),
Estimate.1.Year.Season = c("2017/18", "", "2017/18", "2012/13", "2013/14", ""),
Estimate.1.Objective.... = c("", "", "1A", "1A", "", ""),
Estimate.1.Risk.group.... = c("", "", "2", "2", "", ""),
Estimate.1.Risk.group.description = c("", "", "aged 65 years or older", "aged 65 years or older", "", ""),
Estimate.1.Age.range...lower = c("", "", "65", "65", "", ""),
Estimate.1.Age.range...upper = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
Estimate.1.Sex = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
Estimate.1.Vaccine.... = c("", "", "all vaccines", "all vaccines", "", ""),
Estimate.1.Match...y.n. = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
Estimate.1.Vaccine.strains = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
Estimate.1.Circulating.strains = c("A(H3N2) [dominant]","","","A(H3N2) [dominant]","A(H1N1)pdm09 [dominant]","A(H1N1)pdm09 [dominant]"),
Estimate.1.Outcome.... = c("1", "", "1", "1", "", ""),
Estimate.1.vs.virus..sub.type = c("", "", "influenza A and B", "influenza A", "", ""),
Estimate.1.Measure = c("", "", "aVE (%)", "aVE (%)", "", ""),
Estimate.1.Value = c("", "", "88.5", "34", "", ""),
Estimate.1.CI...lower = c(NA, NA, 38.9,-1, NA, NA),
Estimate.1.CI...upper = c(NA, NA, 97.8, 60, NA, NA),
Estimate.1.Comment = c("","",
"adjusted for age, sex, hospitalisations and GP visits in last 12 months, vaccination status for previous years, underling conditions, deterioration, dependency",
"adjusted for age, sex, underlying medical conditions, BMI, month of illness, and interval from ILI onset","",""),
Estimate.2.Country.... = c("", "", "22", "39", "", ""),
Estimate.2.Year.Season = c("", "", "2018/19", "2013/14", "", ""),
Estimate.2.Objective.... = c("", "", "1A", "1A", "", ""),
Estimate.2.Risk.group.... = c("", "", "2", "2", "", ""),
Estimate.2.Risk.group.description = c("", "", "aged 65 years or older", "aged 65 years or older", "", ""),
Estimate.2.n = c(NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_),
Estimate.2.Age.range...upper = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
Estimate.2.Sex = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
Estimate.2.Vaccine.... = c("", "", "influenza A and B", "all vaccines", "", ""),
Estimate.2.Match...y.n. = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
Estimate.2.Vaccine.strains = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
Estimate.2.Circulating.strains = c("", "", "", "A(H3N2) [dominant]", "", ""),
Estimate.2.Outcome.... = c("", "", "1", "1", "", ""),
Estimate.2.vs.virus..sub.type = c("", "", "influenza A and B", "influenza A", "", ""),
Estimate.2.Measure = c("", "", "aVE (%)", "aVE (%)", "", ""),
Estimate.2.Value = c(NA,NA, 61.7,-25, NA, NA),
Estimate.2.CI...lower = c(NA, NA,-59.9,-96, NA, NA),
Estimate.2.CI...upper = c(NA, NA, 90.9, 20, NA, NA),
Estimate.2.Comment = c("","",
"adjusted for age, sex, hospitalisations and GP visits in last 12 months, vaccination status for previous years, underling conditions, deterioration, dependency",
"adjusted for age, sex, underlying medical conditions, BMI, month of illness, and interval from ILI onset","",""),
Estimate.3.Country.... = c("45", "", "", "39", "", ""),
Estimate.3.Year.Season = c("2017/18", "", "", "2014/15", "", ""),
Estimate.3.Objective.... = c("1A", "", "", "1A", "", ""),
Estimate.3.Risk.group.... = c("2", "", "", "2", "", ""),
Estimate.3.Risk.group.description = c("aged 65 years or older", "", "", "aged 65 years or older", "", ""),
Estimate.3.n = c(NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_),
Estimate.3.N = c(NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_),
Estimate.3.Sex = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
Estimate.3.Vaccine.... = c("1", "", "", "all vaccines", "", ""),
Estimate.3.Match...y.n. = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
Estimate.3.Vaccine.strains = c("", "", "", "", "", ""),
Estimate.3.Circulating.strains = c("A(H3N2) [dominant]", "", "", "A(H3N2) [dominant]", "", ""),
Estimate.3.Outcome.... = c("1", "", "", "1", "", ""),
Estimate.3.vs.virus..sub.type = c("influenza A and B","", "", "influenza A", "", ""),
Estimate.3.Measure = c("uVE (%)","", "", "aVE (%)", "", ""),
Estimate.3.Value = c(4, NA, NA,-22, NA, NA),
Estimate.3.CI...lower = c(-13, NA, NA,-71, NA, NA),
Estimate.3.CI...upper = c(19, NA, NA, 13, NA, NA),
Estimate.3.Comment = c("","","",
"adjusted for age, sex, underlying medical conditions, BMI, month of illness, and interval from ILI onset","",""),
Estimate.4.Country.... = c("45", "", "", "39", "", "")),
row.names = c(NA, 6L),class = "data.frame")
```

As not fully seen in the data above I have 500 columns for individual values that I am looking to gather/pivot longer. Because they are not separated by values such as _ I need to make as many names_to = as names_patterns = are available.

This is my coding, but no matter how I enter REGEX codes it does not appear to work. I would need 22 patterns that recognise strings within column names for example "Country" or "Subtype" and count them as the same variable for lengthening purposes.

```
Data.L %>% pivot_longer(cols = 153:10652,
           names_to = c('Country', '.value', 'Season', '.value', 'Objective', '.value', 'RiskGroup', '.value','RiskGroupDescription', '.value',
                       'n', '.value', 'N', '.value', 'AgeRangeLower', '.value', 'AgeRangerUpper', '.value', 'Sex', '.value', 'Vaccine(#)', '.value',
                       'VaccineMatch', '.value', 'VaccineStrains',  '.value', 'CirculatingStrains', '.value', 'Outcome', '.value',
                       'VirusSubtype', '.value', 'EstimateMeasure', '.value', 'EstimateValue', '.value',
                       'EstimateLowerCI', '.value', 'EstimateUpperCI', '.value', 'Comment', '.value'),
           # names_prefix = 'Estimate.',
           names_patterns = c())
```

Name patterns that I attempted include (BUT certainly not limited to):

```
'(.*Country.*)', '(.*)Year(.*)', '(.*)Objective(.*)', '(.*)Risk.group..(.*)',
                                     '(.*)Risk.group.d(.*)', '(.*)n(.*)', '(.*)N(.*)', '(.*)Age.range...lower(.*)',
                                     '(.*)Age.range...upper(.*)', '(.*)Sex(.*)', '(.*)Vaccine....(.*)', '(.*)Match(.*)',
                                     '(.*)Vaccine.s(.*)', '(.*)Cir(.*)', '(.*)Outcome(.*)', '(.*)vs.(.*)', '(.*)Mea(.*)', '(.*)Value(.*)',
                                     '(.*)CI...lower(.*)', '(.*)CI...upper(.*)', '(.*)Com(.*)'
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated. I am hoping to accomplish this using regex that way I am not manually compiling this via reshape etc.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set `".value"` in `names_to` and supply one of `names_sep` or `names_pattern` to specify how the column names should be split.

```r
library(tidyr)

TEST_table %>%
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to = c("Est", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "([^.]+\\.\\d+)\\.(.+)",
    values_transform = list(Value = as.numeric)
  )

# A tibble: 24 × 22
   Est        Country.... Year.Season Objective.... Risk.group.... Risk.group.description   Age.range...lower Age.range...upper Sex   Vaccine....
   <chr>      <chr>       <chr>       <chr>         <chr>          <chr>                    <chr>             <chr>             <chr> <chr>
 1 Estimate.1 "45"        "2017/18"   ""            ""             ""                       ""                ""                ""    ""
 2 Estimate.2 ""          ""          ""            ""             ""                        NA               ""                ""    ""
 3 Estimate.3 "45"        "2017/18"   "1A"          "2"            "aged 65 years or older"  NA                NA               ""    "1"
 4 Estimate.4 "45"         NA          NA            NA             NA                       NA                NA                NA    NA
 5 Estimate.1 ""          ""          ""            ""             ""                       ""                ""                ""    ""
 6 Estimate.2 ""          ""          ""            ""             ""                        NA               ""                ""    ""
 7 Estimate.3 ""          ""          ""            ""             ""                        NA                NA               ""    ""
 8 Estimate.4 ""           NA          NA            NA             NA                       NA                NA                NA    NA
 9 Estimate.1 "22"        "2017/18"   "1A"          "2"            "aged 65 years or older" "65"              ""                ""    "all vaccines"     
10 Estimate.2 "22"        "2018/19"   "1A"          "2"            "aged 65 years or older"  NA               ""                ""    "influenza A and B"
# … with 14 more rows
```

*Note: `values_transform = list(Value = as.numeric)` gets rid of the following error:*

```
Error in `pivot_longer_spec()`:
! Can't combine `Estimate.1.Value` <character> and `Estimate.2.Value` <double>.
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I have played around with the coding. It does work on my test data, but not on my actual data due to an error: Can't combine `Estimate.1.Country....` <character> and `Estimate.55.Country....` <integer>.     Do I need to specify names_pattern for each variable or is the "Est" sufficient for it to pivot by? Cheers     (with my dataset the columns are specific [x:y] but I dont think that is an issue from what I understand)

Comment: @Hunter That's similar with why I use `values_transform = list(Value = as.numeric)` in `pivot_longer` (I have mentioned it in the last paragraph). Try to add `"Country...." = as.character` in `values_transform` list.

Comment: Hello Darren, great I will work through that. Thank you for your help

Comment: IT was very useful thank you. To follow up for those on Google now, what I did wasadd the line: Data.L.1[, ] <- sapply(Data.L.1[, ], as.character)     this allowed me to then combine all relevant columns. Thanks again Darren